# How do I edebug a function defined in a use-package block?

Tags: use-package, edebug

Here is a minimum working example to demonstrate the problem, you will need to have the [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) package installed:

```
(use-package ido
  :config
  (progn
    (defun dummy/function ()
      (interactive)
      (message "I am in the dummy function."))))
```

When I try to add edebug instrumentation to the `dummy/function` using `M-x edebug-defun`, it starts the edebug rightaway as if I already did `M-x dummy/function`. I have to quit that by hitting `q`. But then when I actually do `M-x dummy/function`, I don't see the edebug activating.

Is there something about the `use-package` wrapper that messes with the edebug instrumentation? How can it be fixed?

Comment: I don't know how use-package works, but does defining `dummy/function` at top-level (i.e., outside of use-package) fix the immediate problem? I've stopped using anonymous lambda functions in favor of named functions to deal with similar sorts of problems in mode-hooks.

Comment: @Yes, functions defined outside the `use-package` wrapper can be edebugged fine. I would like to wrapper everything related to package X inside `(use-package X ..)`, including my custom functions related to X. But if edebug of those functions is an issue, then I would need to rethink my code organization..

Comment: If you think the behavior you are looking for should be provided but is not, consider filing an Emacs enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Be prepared to provide a simple recipe that starts from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: @Drew I sure will do once I figure out if it is an issue with the `use-package` package or emacs. If the function is outside `use-package` wrapper, edebug works fine.

Comment: I think `edebug-defun` debugs the top-level form, which in this case is the `(use-package ...)` itself rather than the defun you are passing in to the `use-package` macro. Can you use `edebug-on-entry` and give the name of the function you've defined?

Comment: FWIW, I use the regular Emacs debugger, `debug`, not `edebug`. For example, `M-x debug-on-entry`. HTH.

Comment: Ask Wiegley. He should be able to tell you how to use `use-package`, including how to debug such problems. ;-)

Comment: @glucas I think you meant `debug-on-entry` and yes that works! Thanks! That can serve as an answer. Thanks @Drew, I used `debug-on-entry` and that serves my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `edebug-defun`

Thanks to @abo-abo for the tip to mark the defun first.

Here is a quick way to enable/disable `edebug-defun`. This uses `search-backward-regexp` to edebug-instrument or eval the defun or defmacro name correctly, whether it is defined in `use-package` wrapper or not.

```el
;; Edebug a defun or defmacro
(defvar modi/fns-in-edebug nil
  "List of functions for which `edebug' is instrumented.")

(defconst modi/fns-regexp (concat "(\\s-*"
                                  "\\(defun\\|defmacro\\)\\s-+"
                                  "\\(?1:\\(\\w\\|\\s_\\)+\\)\\_>") ; word or symbol char
  "Regexp to find defun or defmacro definition.")

(defun modi/toggle-edebug-defun ()
  (interactive)
  (let (fn)
    (save-excursion
      (search-backward-regexp modi/fns-regexp)
      (setq fn (match-string 1))
      (mark-sexp)
      (narrow-to-region (point) (mark))
      (if (member fn modi/fns-in-edebug)
          ;; If the function is already being edebugged, uninstrument it
          (progn
            (setq modi/fns-in-edebug (delete fn modi/fns-in-edebug))
            (eval-region (point) (mark))
            (setq-default eval-expression-print-length 12)
            (setq-default eval-expression-print-level  4)
            (message "Edebug disabled: %s" fn))
        ;; If the function is not being edebugged, instrument it
        (progn
          (add-to-list 'modi/fns-in-edebug fn)
          (setq-default eval-expression-print-length nil)
          (setq-default eval-expression-print-level  nil)
          (edebug-defun)
          (message "Edebug: %s" fn)))
      (widen))))
```

**Usage** - With the point anywhere in the function/macro body, calling `modi/toggle-edebug-defun` will enable or disable `edebug` for that entity.

### `debug-on-entry`

Thanks to @glucas and @Drew, I have cooked up a convenient way to toggle `debug-on-entry`. This also uses the same approach as above to parse the defun/defmacro name.

```el
;; Debug on entry
(defvar modi/fns-in-debug nil
  "List of functions for which `debug-on-entry' is instrumented.")

(defun modi/toggle-debug-defun ()
  (interactive)
  (let (fn)
    (save-excursion
      (search-backward-regexp modi/fns-regexp)
      (setq fn (match-string 1)))
    (if (member fn modi/fns-in-debug)
        ;; If the function is already being debugged, cancel its debug on entry
        (progn
          (setq modi/fns-in-debug (delete fn modi/fns-in-debug))
          (cancel-debug-on-entry (intern fn))
          (message "Debug-on-entry disabled: %s" fn))
      ;; If the function is not being debugged, debug it on entry
      (progn
        (add-to-list 'modi/fns-in-debug fn)
        (debug-on-entry (intern fn))
        (message "Debug-on-entry: %s" fn)))))
```

**Usage** - With the point anywhere in the function body, calling `modi/toggle-debug-defun` will enable or cancel the `debug-on-error` for that function.

Answer (score 9):

When you call `edebug-defun` it debugs the top-level form, which in this case is `(use-package ...)`.

You can use `debug-on-entry` to debug a named function.

Answer (score 6):

1. Mark the appropriate defun and call <kbd>C-x nn</kbd> (`narrow-to-region`)
2. <kbd>C-u C-M-x</kbd> (`edebug-defun`)
3. <kbd>C-x nw</kbd> (`widen`)

If you like doing things quickly, [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) shortcut for this is <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>xe</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>.

Comment: This doesn't work because `narrow-to-defun` narrows to the same `(use-package ...)` form that `edebug-defun` finds. However it does work if you mark the defun first and use `narrow-to-region`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I don't actually use `narrow-to-defun`. `lispy`'s `N` selects region and calls `narrow-to-region`.